# integrated webcam not working in 20.10

Tags: webcam, 20.10

I have a dell precision 7750 laptop. The integrated webcam does not work. OS is ubuntu 20.10

output of sudo lshw:

```
description: Video
product: Integrated_Webcam_HD
vendor: CN0V976R8LG00126A3MPA01
physical id: b
bus info: usb@1:b
 version: 82.68
capabilities: usb-2.01
configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
```

output of ls -l /dev/video*

```
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 May 12 16:43 /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 May 12 16:43 /dev/video1
```

Comment: How have you determined it doesn't work?

Comment: cheese, teams, skype, (even tried open capture device from vlc media player), it always shows black screen

Answer (score 0):

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
device="/dev/whatever"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, but there is one more step.

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.

Comment: I tried the steps but this did not help.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a hardware issue. Dell replaced the camera and it is working now.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1175466)